# Drawing Google pie by dynamic data

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a simple Google pie chart by creating a dynamic table using JavaScript.

Why my code fails?

```
var g;
for (g=0; g <3; g++) {      
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Failed');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Passed');
    data.addRows(1);
    data.setCell(0, 0, "Work?");
    data.setCell(0, 1, 80);
    data.setCell(0, 2, 20);
    var chartName = 'piechart'+(g+1);  
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(chartName));   
    chart.draw(data,options);
}
```

3 pie charts are being drawn on my screen, but they all have one color and one slice, and not 20% 80% like in my code.

Also, I'm not getting any errors on my console.

Comment: what fails exactly, please post the error from your console

Comment: What is the end result you want to see? Do you want a pie chart per task, showing the success failure rate? It's unusual to have more than 2 columns in a piechart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aiming for something like this?
Also if you can, consider using addRows instead of setCell

I think the problem is with your table / data structure.

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="piechart1"></div>
<div id="piechart2"></div>
<div id="piechart3"></div>

<script>
  // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
  google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
  });

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var g;
    for (g = 0; g < 3; g++) {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'PassOrfail');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Percentage');

      data.addRows([
      ['Passed', 80],
      ['Failed', 20],
      ]);
      var chartName = 'piechart' + (g + 1);
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(chartName));
      chart.draw(data);
    }
  }
</script>
```